# How do I display the output of a "while loop" in a table?

Tags: php, html, loops, tabular

I don't even have an idea of where to start for this. I need to display 100 numbers in a table and would like to use a while loop to do so. Is there a "shortcut" to doing this?

Comment: show your code. and what do you mean by `shortcut`?

Comment: Im really not 100% on your issue, you just need to run a while loop and echo the number in a table cell. You can use the `modulus operator (%)` to wrap the cells in a row every `x` results to build your table

Comment: Start by building an HTML table with one row and then include a loop that echoes that row in every iteration with the data you want.

Comment: Read, Do, Read, Do Read, Do.  The only way to learn.  Or hire a programmer.

Comment: @urfusion, there will be no code, if some code than that will be the answer. Cause no complexity arise there.

Comment: @safetybrick, Your answer is ready. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163669/how-do-i-display-the-output-of-a-while-loop-in-a-table/37163800#37163739)

Comment: check the @FrayneKonok answer in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a table you need some tags `table`, `tr` and `td`. The `tr` and `td` are in while loop and the value `$i` will print inside the `td`.

```
<table>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    while($i != 101){?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $i++;?></td></tr>
    <?php }?>   
</table>
```

Comment: it seems the answer OP looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use while, for, foreach for your convenience, like below code

```
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>                    
                <th class="header">Number</th>                              
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                $i = 1;
                while($i != 101){
                ?>
              <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
              </tr>
               <?php
             $i++;
               }  ?>
             </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dipslay 100 numbers simply in tbale like this:

```
<?php 

// Using For loop
echo "<table>";
for ($i = 1;$i <= 100; $i++) { // use for loop
  echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

// OR 

// Using while loop
$i = 1; 
echo "<table>";
while($i <= 100) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td></tr>";
    $i++;
} 
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: OP wants to use `while` loop

Comment: You need to use while as OP said.

Comment: yaa added both methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
while ($i <= 100) {
    echo "<td><tr>" . $i++ . "</tr></td>";
}
```

Comment: If `$i` not incremented then what will be output?

Comment: @FrayneKonok Yup, didn't realise that. Updated post, thanks for pointing out